# Need to modify the product detail page for adding a button beside the add to cart button

Tags: module, addtocart, custom-theme, custom-button

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $buttonTitl = __('Add to C'); ?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitl) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                     disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitl) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Eaglerocket_Customquote::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
               <!-- <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Eaglerocket_Customquote::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
 -->
   </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can you specify which issue you are facing?

Comment: it is visible on some pages and in some it is not visible

Comment: have you try to put your code outside main if?